# Magento Website Specific Pricing

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, store-view, pricing, multi-website

I set a product's price to £9.95 for `Website A`'s store view.

I then set the `Configuration > Catalog > Price > Catalog Price Scope` to be  `Website`.

I go into the product, change the scope top left to `Website B`'s website and set the price to £10.00 and save.

Frontend on `Website B` I still see £9.95. If I go onto the product grid and set `Website B Store View` as the scope it still shows £9.95. But if I then click the product it shows £10.00.

Am I doing something wrong? I just need the price to be different frontend on `Website B`!

If there is a possible plugin causing this functionality to be overwritten, how can I troubleshoot that?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't even change the price to another website on product page How did you do that? here: :https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/214688/magento-2-new-website-not-displaying-in-drop-down-on-product-page-admin

Comment: Hi this is Magento 1 which might be why it's different!